# How to make database updates and state changes in React show up across all connected pages?

Tags: reactjs, database, synchronization

I have a task in hand where I have a page A, where I can drag and drop to reorder certain components displayed as a list and another page B, which simply displays the list to the user without allowing any changes of order, and these two pages are supposed to stay updated with their current state. Any changes on page A should be reflected on page B without having to reload it. I do store my changes in a MongoDB database, and refreshing page B shows the updated order. And I know I can make the page update without refreshing it by simply making the page itself check after each x second the current condition of the database, but that feels resource heavy. Is there a better way to do this?

This is the fragment where I need the changes to happen. dragAndDrop is a prop item that is true on page A but false on page B.

```
<React.Fragment>
{
    dragAndDrop ?
    (
        <Draggable draggableId={result.id} index={index}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div 
                className={snapshot.isDragging ? "result-card dragging" : "result-card"}
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
                <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span className="math-result">= { result.result }</span>
                    <span className="calculation-title">{ result.title }</span>
                    <button className="cstm-btn-red" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>See Input</button>
                    <Modal open={this.state.isOpen} onClose={() => this.closeModal()}>
                        { result.inputContent }
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    ) :
    (
        <div className="result-card">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span className="math-result">= { result.result }</span>
                <span className="calculation-title">{ result.title }</span>
                <button className="cstm-btn-red" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>See Input</button>
                <Modal open={this.state.isOpen} onClose={() => this.closeModal()}>
                    { result.inputContent }
                </Modal>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
</React.Fragment>
```

I'm still rather fresh to React JS and am learning more and more each day. I feel like there should be a discussion regarding my issue somewhere out there.
But I have been unable to find it. So, sorry for the post probably being a duplicate.

Comment: Well the real time updates you're wanting can be done via sockets. `socket.io` is probably the most popular tool for it, and it has a Mongo DB adapter: https://socket.io/docs/v4/mongo-adapter/  but honestly, just doing a request every few seconds isn't really that crazy or heavy, it's called polling and it's a simple, common technique to keep things up to date. Probably better just to stick to polling, rather than going to all the effort of setting up a socket connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to store all the updates is to use [Redux](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjm36fV0cn1AhUSrlYBHbxYATEQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Freact-redux.js.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw11ikOiF0Q6Nqf7KBld6PZw) or [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or the [local storage](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi08Nve0sn1AhWLrlYBHR3eBDcQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fhtml%2Fhtml5_webstorage.asp&usg=AOvVaw3TLSJPuOPKIFu85x7TQ48y) of browser, you will have to go the links given to understand more. Basically, they store all the changes user is making without reloading any pages and it will persist till the user closes the tab.

If you want to store them permanently, I recommend calling the API ONCE he gets OUT of the page A ( you will have to track the page URLs or use useEffect return function to call this API - these seem difficult to understand first for a beginner but once you understand the useEffect hooks or react-router hooks, its very easy to do this)
and store his order in DB but also simultaneously update the redux state or context API state or local storage. Normally, we use redux for this which gives lot of advantages compared to Context or local storage.